# Apache server restart with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, amazon-ec2

I have just restarted my apache server which is running ruby on rails. Now it isn't serving any web pages because I think that some of the Rails related services are not working.

Does anyone know how to sort this out? Any help greatly appreciated.

More info: error says "Ruby on Rails application could not be started" with Phusion Passenger on the front page.

The application was working before the restart and I have changed some javascript on one of the ruby generated html pages. No major config changes.

Comment: What does it say in the Apache and Rails logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys - thanks for all of the feedback. You don't need to restart apache Web server , you  just need to do following steps to restart passenger

cd /home/veriqual/r2/
touch tmp/restart.txt

Hope this helps people.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have it setup properly? If it only started failing after a restart, chances are you made a bad change to your config. Here's a sample configuration (/etc/apache2/sites-available/site):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.site.com
  DocumentRoot /var/rails/site/public
  <Directory /var/rails/site/public>                                                                                                       
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Make sure apache has access to your app's folder. Usually, apache runs as www-data.